# Running QT application from command prompt in Windows 7

Tags: windows, qt, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am new to QT and want to run QT application from command prompt along with some command line arguments
I have the ".exe" file of my application. When I run the application from QT creator using command line arguments, it runs well but I am unable to figure out how to pass the same command line arguments through command prompt while executing the application

If i run ".exe" file (without passing any arguments) it executes successfully but i need to pass arguments for some extra features.

Comment: This would be a good case for a [MCVE] that just prints the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried something like

```
<applicationName> <arg1> <arg2> <argn>
```

?

Comment: yes i have tried. the arguments in my qtcreator are something like "-arg1=value" and in command line i tried this by "myapp.exe"  "-arg1=value"

Comment: Why is there so many "" ? 
More over, doing "myapp -arg1=value" (the exe is not necessary) is a valid syntax for your command line. However, I don't really know if QtCreator does something in addition to your arguments (adding argument, preprocessing them, etc.)

Comment: I tried "myapp -arg1=value" but i get an error unrecognized internal or external command

Comment: Try just "myapp -arg1 value" then